# inline javascript trigger doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
html = '<a href="#" onclick="alert("This link is clickable only in the mobile!")">text</a>'
```

I append my html but when I click it says Unexpected token }, is it impossible to do the inline trigger like that?

Comment: The problem is with quotes nesting, use \' inside the alert

Comment: I'll recommend you not to use inline handlers, use `addEventListener` to bind events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` characters in property values... Use the [`&quot;` special entity](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref):

```
html = '<a href="#" onclick="alert(&quot;This link is clickable only in the mobile!&quot;)">text</a>'
```

There are better options to achieve this instead of writing raw HTML in JavaScript.

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
var aElement = jQuery("<a>").attr("href", "#").click(function() {
    alert("This link is clickable only in the mobile!");
});
// You can append it like:
aElement.appendTo(document.body);
```

Pure Javascript:

```
var aElement = document.createElement("a");
aElement.setAttribute("href", "#");
// If you want the onclick attribute to show up in HTML source:
aElement.setAttribute("onclick", "alert(\"This link is clickable only in the mobile!\")");
// This way is easier:
aElement.onclick = function() {
    alert("This link is clickable only in the mobile!");
}
// Append like:
document.body.appendChild(aElement);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible exactly like that because you're mixing double quotes.

Use an escaped single quote inside your string:

```
html='<a href="#" onclick="alert(\'This link is clickable only in the mobile!\')">text</a>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html = '<a href="javascript:alert(&quot;This link is clickable only in the mobile!&quot;)">text</a>'
```

You can directcly attach javascript method in anchor's `href` also you need to encode (escape) quotes.